# use sed to replace nbsp, 160, Hex 00a0, Octal 240, non-breaking space

Tags: linux, vim, sed, special-characters

I am having some problems with config files which have the [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) chars in them.

How should I specify that character with sed so I can replace it with a space.

```
sed -n 's/ / /g'
```

examples of the errors

```
service named restart
Stopping named:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting named: 
Error in named configuration:
named.localhost:2: unknown RR type 'SOA '
named.localhost:8: unknown RR type '@'
named.localhost:9: unknown RR type '127.0.0.1'
named.localhost:10: unknown RR type '::1'
.....
```

I tried to include a line form the original offending file in this post. It does not seams to be working. Pastebin download seams to be the only tool that keeps all the original binary. http://pastebin.com/ZqT1EWbS. You should be able to copy and past the original line and have it work in your terminal.

Comment: you could googled for a sed manual, and look up hex you'd see you can specify characters in hex e.g. the non-breaking space \xA0   You can specify in decimal too.  \d160  but you know when you look up hex in the manual it'd be talking about specifying characters in hex. There are a small handful of mentions of decimal so it's not hard to look up decimal in the manual either.  I have a manual for GNU 4.2.1 of Sed. It has about \d and \x  specifying hex.

Comment: @barlop can you paste a link to documentation that demonstrates hex and decimal use of sed.

Comment: mine is from gnuwin32 sed comes with a pdf. There is a manual online here http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html   do edit..find..hex  you find the same contents (though I see in one place, one heading like "some sample scripts" in my pdf, vs "examples" in that one, differ very slightly) but most of rest is same word for word, I could edit..find phrases in one and find the same content in the other and the same smaller significant headings too.   so details are the same. It seems to be probably almost  identical to what I have.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The answer to this question depends on which of the non-breaking space characters you are encountering.

Below are examples of how to replace each of the non-breaking space characters mentioned in the questions title and additionally the UTF-8 version (`C2 A0`) that the OP is actually asking about according to the pastebin output.

All examples use `printf` to generate the output as it is more portable than `echo`. The space characters are replaced by `X`'s to make the output clearer.

### Examples

#### html

```
printf '&#nbsp;\n' | sed 's/&#nbsp;/X/g'
printf '&#160;\n'  | sed 's/&#160;/X/g'
printf '&#xA0;\n'  | sed 's/&#x[aA]0;/X/g'
```

#### octal 240 = decimal 160 = hex A0

```
printf '\xA0\n' | sed 's/\xA0/X/g'
```

Or with `tr`:

```
printf '\xA0\n' | tr '\240' 'X'
```

#### U+00A0

```
printf '\x00\xA0\n' | sed 's/\x00\xA0/X/g'
```

#### UTF-8

```
printf '\xC2\xA0\n' | sed 's/\xC2\xA0/X/g'
```

#### Result

Output in all of the above cases is:

```
X
```

### Answer

Now to your question, you have data that looks like this:

```
printf '@       IN SOA  @ rname.invalid. (' | od -x
```

Output:

```
0000000 c240 c2a0 c2a0 c2a0 c2a0 c2a0 20a0 4e49
0000020 5320 414f a0c2 4020 7220 616e 656d 692e
0000040 766e 6c61 6469 202e 0a28
0000052
```

In order to replace the `C2 A0`s with ordinary space, use this:

```
printf '@       IN SOA  @ rname.invalid. (' | sed 's/\xC2\xA0/ /g' | od -x
```

Output:

```
0000000 2040 2020 2020 2020 4e49 5320 414f 2020
0000020 2040 6e72 6d61 2e65 6e69 6176 696c 2e64
0000040 2820 000a
0000044
```

Comment: what does the -n do? maybe I did something wrong but without -n it works. with -n I get no output and the file remains the same

Comment: @barlop: it makes sed not print the pattern space, and is not supposed to be there. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: If one wanted to do the sed destructively rather than constructively(to borrow a phrase that I think is from programming), you can do   C:\>sed -i "s/\xA0/ /g" a.txt     It's probably better to  do it constructively as you have. But that's a line which will show nothing on the screen, but do something(I mention it since we mentioned suppressing output). sed -i t writes the result into a.txt  or works in a.txt so the desired output is in there, and no output on screen.

Comment: I would probably add to @barlop's response to suggest, assuming they want to save the changes to the file, `sed -i.orig 's/\xa0/ /g'` That way it't updates the original file but saves the originial as `originalname.txt.orig` (or whatever extension specified, such as .bak)

Comment: Unicode no-break space is U+00A0, which is encoded as C2 A0 in UTF-8. If your file is encoded in UTF-8, `sed 's/\xa0/ /g'` will remove only the A0 character and leave the C2. That is, at least the behaviour I'm seeing, even with a UTF-8 locale in use.

Comment: @senarvi: You are correct, I have expanded the answer to account for this. Thanks.

Comment: `tr` is equivalent to sed's `y` command

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all those who help me get to a working solution.

I tried to include a line form the original offending file in this post. It does not seams to be working. Pastebin download seams to be the only tool that keeps all the original binary. http://pastebin.com/ZqT1EWbS. You should be able to copy and past the original line and have it work in your terminal.

So here is what happens if I remove the octal `\0240` or hex `\xA0`. It adds some other funky characters.

```
$ echo "@       IN SOA  @ rname.invalid. (" | sed -e "s/\xA0//g"
@������ IN SOA� @ rname.invalid. (
```

There is some extra data not printed in the actual files. I found the [od (octal dump)](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl_od.htm) tool quite useful to show me what the actual hex / oct / binary values for the whole line are.

```
$ echo "@       IN SOA  @ rname.invalid. (" | od -x
0000000 c240 c2a0 c2a0 c2a0 c2a0 c2a0 20a0 4e49
0000020 5320 414f a0c2 4020 7220 616e 656d 692e
0000040 766e 6c61 6469 202e 0a28
0000052
```

The other character that kept showing up was `\xC2` It is not printed when the non breaking space `\xA0` is there, but shows up if the nbsp is removed. So I had to modify the sed line in the [@Thor answer](https://superuser.com/a/517852/67952)  to remove it as well.

This is what worked for me.

```
$ echo "@       IN SOA  @ rname.invalid. (" | sed -e "s/\xC2\xA0/ /g"
@       IN SOA  @ rname.invalid. (
```

Comment: looks like the characters get broken when putting it in pastebin too. Here is the output I get from that echo line http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=KfWPSXWN  notice the hex is different from your hex. Can you upload the file to http://ge.tt/ ?  (I know you solved it's still worthwhile).

Comment: @barlop http://ge.tt/72UA2QT/v/0

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ZqT1EWbS does not work. Go the link directly http://pastebin.com/ZqT1EWbS. and use the raw out section at the bottom. I tested it and it worked as I expect. I think it is probably some thing to do with the web browser / server / php doing character conversion / filtering.

Comment: I think non-breaking spaces can come out funny when you pipe them to some commands, od included. so for me,  echo a <non-brekaing spaces> | od -tx1   prints  61 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 0d 0a.  So to remove my non-breaking spaces, I have to do echo a      b    | sed "s/\xff/we/g"   Your non-breaking spaces come out funny but a different funny code to my funny code.  (I can copy/paste non-breaking spaces that echo outputs, so echo doesn't mess them up, but  they get messed up when piped). So what we're able to do, is use sed but on the messed up codes, and we see them with od..

Comment: and by the way, I suggest od -tx1 or -td1 for decimal. as I find it looks clearer like that and you might too. Weirdly  things can come out backwards otherwise. Try echo abc | od -x.  Then try with | od -tx1   I am not sure why when you did od -x it didn't come out backwards or maybe it did i'm not sure. I can't test as my scrambled code was ff. But compare -tx1 with -x, and see what you think.

Comment: @barlop my bad looks like pastbin was remembering my session. When I cleared my cache and cookies it dose not work. The download option does work though. Will edit to make that clear.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6706/discussion-between-barlop-and-nelaar)

Comment: Here's another one who had to take care of \xC2 after a pdftotext output result gave some headaches.

Comment: you can also use `xxd` to print out the text along the side of the hex dump. Try running `command | xxd | vim -` to view the file with syntax highlighting.

Comment: As mentioned in a comment to [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/518277/133552) by _senarvi_, your file seems to be encoded as UTF-8 where non-breaking space characters are specified as `C2 A0`, see the [encodings section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Encodings) of the wikipedia page. I have expanded my answer to account for this. I see you found the correct solution to deal with this.

Answer (score 2):

## Replace non-breaking space with space in a UTF-8 file

The TLDR version of [Thors answer](https://superuser.com/a/517852)

```sh
sed -i 's/\xC2\xA0/ /g' filename
```